# Error in the code, BuildContext in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app with different build methods so that I can make a list of items to save them on another screen when the "love heart" button is tapped. But I am getting errors in the code. I am following the [Flutter Codelabs app tutorial part 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#0). 
My code:

```
import 'package:aioapp2/lists.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {
  final _suggestions = [];
  final Set<Widget> _saved = Set<Widget>();

Widget _buildList() {
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 53,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
  },
);
  }

Widget _buildRow(Widget website){
  final bool alreadySaved = _saved.contains(website);
  return Card(
    child: Container(
      child: ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
        subtitle: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
          // Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: _buildList(),
  );
}
}

class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
}
```

The error that I'm facing is in the *Image.asset() line*. On typing the following line its showing red line under the "index". But it shouldn't and that's the problem! Any help?

Comment: where is the error? you didn't mention the issue you're facing

Comment: sorry I dont know how i missed that I've edited the question thanks for correcting me

Comment: I can't find ``images`` and ``index`` variables declared in your ``_buildRow`` function. You need to pass the index to the widget function inorder to access

Comment: `index` isn't a variable and `images` is a list. I actually want to iterate the list of my images into the listview  _index wise_

Comment: ignore about ``images``. but you're trying to use ``index`` in a function in which it's not declared.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to reference the variable `index` from within the `_buildRow` method, but that variable doesn't exist there. Take a look at this excerpt from your code

```dart
Widget _buildList() {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 53,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { // <-- index declared here
      return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
    },
  );
}

Widget _buildRow(Widget website){
  final bool alreadySaved = _saved.contains(website);
  return Card(
    child: Container(
      child: ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
        subtitle: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            // Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'), // <-- index has not been declared here
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

This is an example of scope. The variable `index` is defined in the builder method within `_buildList`. That means the variable only exists there. You can't access it outside that method, so when you try to access it within `_buildRow`, you get an error.

If you want to pass the value of index to the `_buildRow`, you need to pass it as an argument to the `_buildRow` method:

```dart
Widget _buildList() {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 53,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { // <-- index declared here
      return _buildRow(_suggestions[index], index); // Passing it as an argument
    },
  );
}

Widget _buildRow(Widget website, int index) {
  final bool alreadySaved = _saved.contains(website);
  return Card(
    child: Container(
      child: ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
        subtitle: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'), // <-- index has been declared in the parameter list so everything is ok here
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

(Your code doesn't declare `images` anywhere either, but I'm assuming you declare it elsewhere in code that you didn't share since you aren't reporting the error there.)

Comment: well the code is not giving errors now but still on running in the emulator its showing error. what now?

Comment: `RangeError(index) : Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0` this is the error showing in the emulator

Comment: if you want to you can take a look at all my code [here](https://github.com/theyashjha/aioapp)

Comment: @YashJha The problem is you create `_suggestions = []` and never fill it. So when you pass `itemCount: 53` to the ListView, you're assuming there are 53 elements in `_suggestions` when it's still an empty list. Either put (at least) 53 items in `_suggestions` or change it to `itemCount: _suggestions.length`.

Comment: Ok so now I have changed the value of `itemCount:`, but its showing plain white background rather than showing the `buildList()` method in the `body:`. What now?

Comment: @YashJha Presumably you went with the `itemCount: _suggestions.length` route. In that case, it's a white background because the list is empty. It isn't going to build any items if there are no items to build.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this a simple workaround:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    home: FavoriteList(),
  )
);


class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {
  final _suggestions = [{
      'image' : 'ic_play.png'
    },
    {
      'image' : 'ic_play.png'
    },
    {
      'image' : 'ic_play.png'
    },
    {
      'image' : 'ic_play.png'
    }
  ];

  final Set<Widget> _saved = Set<Widget>();

Widget _buildList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _suggestions.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
      },
    );
  }

Widget _buildRow(dynamic website){
  return Card(
    child: Container(
      child: ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
        subtitle: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('assets/images/${website['image']}'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: _buildList(),
  );
}
}

class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt

```
Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
```

be like

```
Image.asset('lib/images/${index}.png'), // Provide you have 0.png, 1.png .... in lib folder
```

Or you should had an String array names images like

```
String[] images=["1.png","2.png"];
```

=====
I cant see any variable images which you want to reference in the commented code.